# Why does my CSS animation, which I copied from a tutorial, not work?

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to make a very simple google dinosaur style game, where an "obstacle" constantly slides towards the "character". To do that, I have made some css code exactly the way the guy in the tutorial did it. I included a snippet of it below.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.game {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
.character {
    height: 50px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}
@keyframes block{
    0%{left: 480px;}
    100%{left: -40px;}
}
.obstacle {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    left: 480px;
    animation: block is infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Jumping Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jump.css">
</head>
<div>

    <body>
        <div class="game">
            <div class="character">

            </div>
            <div class="obstacle">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</div>
<script src="jump.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Attach the link to tutorial pls

Comment: The problem is there is no jump.js file so that might be the thing messing up the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare animation duration property like this.

```
 animation: block 0.5s infinite;
```